# Travis CI "ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: database "jobTrak_test" does not exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, travis-ci

So, I've been working on a Rails project all night, and decided Travis would be nice because I can push changes to GitHub from my Windows machine (which testing does not work on) to Travis, and on successful build/testing, I can pull the latest version to the server.

However, in order to protect my personal details, the database.yml and and secrets.yml have been put into .gitingore and replaced with example files.

Because of this, I need to do a little extra work with Travis to get it to generate the database.

.travis.yml:

```
# Travis CI Configuration
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.3
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database jobTrak_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
```

database.yml.travis:

```
# Database config
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: jobTrak_test
  username: postgres
```

[Travis Build Log](https://travis-ci.org/KarmaLaBelle/jobTrak/builds/114492873)

I'm not seeing anything else online, so I'm clearly doing something wrong here.

If you need any other information, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the db rails way

```
before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding services and before_script entries to the .travis.yml fixed a similar error for me

```
language: ruby

bundler_args: --without production

services:
  - postgresql

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database marina_test;' -U postgres
```

Take a look at the travis docs:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify the DB type with :

```
env:
  - DB=pgsql
```

NOTE: postgresql and postgres WILL NOT WORK. Please use pgsql !!!

Here is the full code that worked for me:

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.2

env:
  - DB=pgsql

services:
  - postgresql

script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rake

before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database courseselect_test;' -U postgres
```

config/database.yml.travis

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_developement
```

BTW, I also have file `config/database.yml` with the same content as `config/database.yml.travis`